# How to open context Menu at specific position in Android and not as menu dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contextmenu

How to have context menu open at specify place like the below image. The application is doubleTwistPlayer - See on [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer)

[image: double twist list ellipsis]

On Clicking it open context menu there itself, instead of a context menu dialog

[image: on clicking the ellipsis, menu open here]

---

Already Tried

**menu_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/itemApplyNew"
        android:title="@string/applyNew"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/itemAppliedLeaves"
        android:title="@string/appliedLeaves"/>    


</menu>
```

**list_item.xml(since I want to implement this in list)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<!-- <RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/relUpperBody"
    android:background="@color/listViewTopContentBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvLeaveName"
    style="@style/ListViewItemHeaderText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
    android:text="sdfsdfsd" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvBalanceLeave"
    style="@style/ListViewItemHeaderText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgLeaveAction"
    android:text="dsfgd" />
<!-- </RelativeLayout> -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvAllottedLbl"
    style="@style/ListViewItemTextSize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txvLeaveName"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/allotted" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvAllottedLeave"
    style="@style/ListViewItemTextSize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txvBalanceLeave"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txvAllottedLbl"
    android:text="sgsdg" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLeaveAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ellipsis_menu_overflow" />
```

---

**Question**

1. How to implement it?
2. Is it context menu or something else?

Comment: Ok, i will share. Wait

Comment: @JordiCastilla see now.

Comment: you`re close, your list layout connot `match_parent`, must be smaller. Also give it a position relative depending the caller when shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

> **Popup menu**
>    A popup menu displays a list of items in a vertical list that's anchored to the view that invoked the menu. It's good for
>   providing an overflow of actions that relate to specific content or to
>   provide options for a second part of a command. Actions in a popup
>   menu should not directly affect the corresponding content—that's what
>   contextual actions are for. Rather, the popup menu is for extended
>   actions that relate to regions of content in your activity.

More about implementing it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu).

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation and dev link.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a ListPopupWindow, all you need to do is create a callback from your list adapter to your fragment / activity and pass the clicked view in the callback as a parameter and using the ListPopupWindow set the anchor point to the view you have passed, you can create your own custom adapter and set it to the ListPopupWindow and pass the list of items that you want to show in the pop up, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pop-up menu.
Android Popup Menu displays the menu below the anchor text if space is available otherwise above the anchor text. It disappears if you click outside the popup menu.

check it [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example).